555 IC - Role of Resistor in Capacitor Discharge (Astable mode)
I can't grasp the role of resistor Ra in this circuit.

I know that when the output from the SR latch is low, the transistor doesn't allow the capacitor to discharge. And when the output is high, discharge is allowed.
What I don't understand is: when we replace Ra with a wire or set low resistance values for it, the capacitor can't discharge anymore.

I tried building a similar circuit using 555 to test this. When I set R3 to 0, the LED doesn't blink anymore. This is also true for low resistance values for R3.
The circuit on the right also shows that when R5 is set to 0 and the button is pressed, the capacitor doesn't discharge completly - which happens when R5 has some resistance (I measured it with a voltmeter).
Can someone explain to me the importance of Ra (or R3) and why the capacitor can't discharge when this resistor is absent, like in the circuit below?


Did yoe remove Ra, or replaced it with short circuit? What does your new schematic looks like? Did you just leave pin 7 floating, connected to supply, or connected to Rb or what?

It can't discharge, but only because it can't charge in the first place

@Justme I replaced it with a wire.

@Finbarr it charges and stay charged.

Removing a resistor is not the same as replacing it with a short circuit.

@Finbarr Sorry, I edited the post.

So you replaced Ra with 0 ohm wire basically.
The discharge pin 7 connects to ground to discharge the capacitor, but since you short-circuited pin 7 with a pìece of wire to supply voltage, pin 7 can't discharge the capacitor. It may damage the 555 IC, but also if your supply is a 9V cube battery, it can't provide much current and your IC might be fine.

When resistor Ra exists and the transistor is active, current flow through Ra -> Transistor -> ground AND from the capacitor -> Rb -> transistor -> ground, right? When replacing Ra with a wire, current only flows from Ra -> transistor and not through the other path? I am having trouble visualizing the short-circuit here, sorry.

If the circuit were ideal, and you replace the Ra with a piece of wire, the capacitor can only charge to 9V through Rb and discharge pin is shorted to 9V. When discharge transistor turns on, your ideal 9V battery provides infinite amount of current into discarge pin and yet the capacitor can't discharge as it is only pulled up to 9V by Rb.

Thanks a lot! Now I understood it.
